# Access data in objects angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A customer In my application can have one of these objects:

```
[Object { fb="7143267", date="2009-11-24 13:12:35", $$hashKey="00Z"}, Object { fb="FB-7213400", date="2010-04-22 15:28:47", $$hashKey="010"}]
```

or

```
Object { fb="FB-9202725", date="2014-05-09 08:20:46"}
```

These objects belongs to an other object called abbData.

I don't know how to print out the FB value and the date value when the object contains more values.

I have tried the following:

```
<tr><td><strong>FB#</strong></td><td ng-repeat="fb in summary.abbData.fb">{{fb}} ({{fb.date}})</td></tr>
```

This works when the object only contains ONE FB value and ONE date value, but when It contains more values, I get the following output:

```
{"fb":"7143267","date":"2009-11-24 13:12:35"} (2009-11-24 13:12:35)
```

How can I make my code work when the object also contains more values?

Comment: should not be there loop if you have more objects ??

Comment: @ozil: What do you mean?

Comment: I guess that you shall iterate through the abbData since this is the array (as i understand). So:<tr><td><strong>FB#</strong></td><td ng-repeat="fb in summary.abbData">{{fb}} ({{fb.date}})</td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

this may help you :

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in summary.abbData">
     <td>
          <strong>FB#</strong>
     </td>
     <td>
           {{data.fb}} ({{data.date}})
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want to Iterate over my whole object. I only want to Iterate over summary.abbData.fb